# Can't change `android:textColor` for a button using a theme

Tags: android, kotlin, android-button, android-styles

Hello I have a simple android application in which I have a button. This is the default theme of my application: `themes.xml`

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.BaseAppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
    <style name="Theme.WalkTest" parent="Theme.BaseAppTheme">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

In a separate file, `button.xml` I've defined the theme for my button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.WalkTest.ButtonSecondary" parent="Theme.WalkTest">
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and here is the button I have in my fragment: `fragment_buildings.xml` (I'm using navigation).

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/create_building_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_add"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:text="@string/new_building"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.WalkTest.ButtonSecondary"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />
```

Here is android studio's preview:

[image: button text still white]

I can see that the background change is working, however the `textColor` doesn't seem to change?
I can use the attributes on the button element to change its colour, but I wanna have reusable styles.

This is my Android Studio version:

```
Android Studio 4.1
Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6858069, built on September 23, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.15.7
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 2014M
Cores: 4
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: IdeaVIM, org.jetbrains.kotlin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
style = "@style/Theme.WalkTest.ButtonSecondary"
```

instead of

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.WalkTest.ButtonSecondary"
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Define your styles in values/styles.xml

**Example:**

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">  
            <style name="text_h3">
                        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
                        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
                        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/font_medium</item>
                        <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
                        <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
                        <item name="android:background">?android:attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
            </style>
</resource>
```

Second, Utilize the defined style for the required view,

**Example:**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_name_label"
    style="@style/text_h3"
    ...
</TextView>
```

This is one of the right ways to go ahead with styling, hope this helped you.

Comment: This is an example of applying a style directly to a `View`. The question, however, was about applying styling through a theme.

Comment: @homerman no it's actually fine. I just wanted a way to define styles and apply them hahah.